# Filtering data and saving query results

Tags: database, search

Something i've been struggling to find an answer to for a couple of weeks now.

I am in the middle of building a wordpress based website and one of the requirements is to create a search page on the site that will search a table of data and return an index of any results there are. If there are no results it will need to return a shortcode (that will generate a contact form using the ninja forms plugin).

The other requirement is that the queries submitted from the search bar will need to then be stored for review, i would guess either in a table of date (although I don't think this would be ideal long term) or something like a JSON file.

Any pointers would be appreciated folks.

Thanks

Comment: Hi KKBSE2016. As initially posted, these are fairly broad questions and you've supplied no code. If you could break things down into separate questions and provide the code that you've got so far, you'd have better odds of getting help from the community.

Comment: Hi Dave,

This is it, i'm on a total blank canvas at the moment. I have a .csv file with 3 columns of data on it and thats it so far. I was thinking of storing this data in an sql database table on the wp install but then have no idea what to use to perform the search on that data only. 

The questions I guess would be:

- Is storing it in SQL the best option? 
- Does wordpress already have a function to search this data and store the queries as well as returning an index of results to the user?
- If not should I turn to something more complex like Solr or Elasticsearch.